# task-concatenation in WinRT, why cannot use task::wait?

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-runtime, concurrency-runtime

In my current project I have had a recent issue and have trouble understanding it:

```
concurrency::create_task(BPClient->ReadAnswer()).then([this](Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<unsigned char>^ Vec) {
            WSS::InMemoryRandomAccessStream^ imras = ref new WSS::InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            WSS::DataWriter^ dw = ref new WSS::DataWriter(imras->GetOutputStreamAt(0));
            for(long long i = 0; i < Vec->Size; i++){
                dw->WriteByte(Vec->GetAt(i));
            }
            concurrency::create_task(dw->StoreAsync()).then([this, imras](unsigned int Count){
                Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage^ bi = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage();
                Image^ img = ref new Image();
                bi->SetSource(imras);
                img->Source = bi;
                img->Width = 400;
                img->Height = 400;
                img->SetValue(Grid::ColumnProperty, 2);
                concurrency::create_task(coredisp->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([=]() {
                    this->MainGrid->Children->Append(img);
                })));
            });
        });
```

This works fine and produces the expected result. But, if I change it to

```
concurrency::create_task(BPClient->ReadAnswer()).then([this](Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<unsigned char>^ Vec) {
            WSS::InMemoryRandomAccessStream^ imras = ref new WSS::InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            WSS::DataWriter^ dw = ref new WSS::DataWriter(imras->GetOutputStreamAt(0));
            for(long long i = 0; i < Vec->Size; i++){
                dw->WriteByte(Vec->GetAt(i));
            }

            concurrency::create_task(dw->StoreAsync()).wait(); //consider this line
            Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage^ bi = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage();
            Image^ img = ref new Image();
            bi->SetSource(imras);
            img->Source = bi;
            img->Width = 400;
            img->Height = 400;
            img->SetValue(Grid::ColumnProperty, 2);
            concurrency::create_task(coredisp->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([=]() {
                this->MainGrid->Children->Append(img);
            }))).wait();
        });
```

I eventually receive an error that an invalid parameter was passed to the last `concurrency::create_task`-call.

What is actually going on here? Is it not possible to mix `concurrency::task::then` and `concurrency::task::wait`? I think I am creating a similar task chain as when using `concurrency::task::wait` instead of `concurrency::task::then`.
Thank you

Comment: Please post the exact error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

In c++/cx that error is thrown when you wait on the UI thread, which you can't do. But if you're just appending to the xaml document you shouldn't have to wait.